# Wordpress Attachment/image post parent's value not changing

Tags: wordpress, attachment

I added an image from medialibrary to standart Wordpress post. In it's content area. This image got post parent's value of that post's id.

Now I deleted this image from that post's content area and saved post. I can see in db that post parent's value of this image still contains ID of that post. It's not changing to 0.

What's wrong with it? Why isn't it changing? Medialibrary still shows that this image has relations to that post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once uploaded for a post the item is connected to that for ever. It's not unchained when you remove it as featured image or from the content. The mechanisme simply tells you 'you uploaded image Y when you were editing post X'.

Additionally; when you insert the image you already uploaden into another post, it will not change the parent of that image.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I've already noticed that if I insert the same image to another post or page, post parent value still stays the same. Well, I think it's still strange behaviour of Wordpress, cause it doesn't make sence to me. But now I know that it's in the core :)